# How can I undo the last cd command?

Tags: command-line, bash

Is there any way to jump back to the previous working directory after doing a `cd` to a different directory?

My use-case is that I'm traversing a directory structure for a Java project, and I'm expecting that the current directory has only one sub-directory. So, I type `cd` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather quickly. However, the <kbd>Tab</kbd> failed, as I mistakenly expected one sub-directory, when in fact there are more. So now, I just executed `cd`, and am now in my home directory, instead of the Java project. Is there a way to "undo" this `cd` and jump back to the directory I was in?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You can use `cd -` to go back to your previous location, no matter where that was.

Answer (score 22):

`cd -` is great for going back one level, but if you find yourself wanting to go back a few levels, check out this script:

[acd_func.sh](https://gist.github.com/SkyRocknRoll/5114846)

It's great. `cd --` to see your history, and `cd -3` to go back 3 levels, for example.

Comment: Wow... a geocities link. Now there's a URL I have not seen in a long time. <insert Obi-wan JPG>

Comment: the [gist](https://gist.github.com/SkyRocknRoll/5114846) of this comment.  <jpg Yoda insert>

Answer (score 18):

You can also use `pushd` and `popd` to utilize the directory stack. [Here's some information.](http://eriwen.com/bash/pushd-and-popd/)

Answer (score 6):

In addition, `cd ..` can take you **back** to the working directory's **parent** directory and then if necessary the command can be repeated until you get to where you want to be. In fact, each time it is evoked it takes you back through the directory tree, which would ultimately finish at `/` (the root directory) **if** you just kept repeating the command.

In **contrast**, `cd -` actually makes the previous working directory the current working directory, (which is known as `.`), and which exact location in the filesystem can be found with `pwd`.

So both `cd ..` and `cd -`  can be useful in different circumstances when navigating the directory tree, although they do **differ** in the aforementioned respects. Perhaps the most useful command after having fun experimenting with these two commands is `cd`, which returns you to the home folder.

Answer (score -1):

Best way to do this for going back is `cd -`, however if you want to skip a lot of levels at once, you better use `cd ..` for one level, `cd ../..`, for two, `cd ../../..` for three and on... a nice way to do it fast is this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "Number of folders to move back: "
read TIMES
BACKCHARS=../
BACK=$(for i in `seq $TIMES`; do printf $BACKCHARS; done)
cd $BACK
```

Comment: Running `cd` in a script doesn't affect the parent shell. You'd need to put this in a shell function for it to be useful.

Comment: like this: `up(){ local n="$1"; while ((n--)); do path+='../'; done; cd "$path"; }`