# How do I move back to original directory?

Tags: command-line

First i did `pwd`, it says:

```
/home/user
```

I changed my directory using :

```
cd /Italic/Food/Places
```

Now, I want to go back to original directory: `/home/user`. How can I do this?

Comment: cd ~ will go in home

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I undo the last cd command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164380/how-can-i-undo-the-last-cd-command)

Answer (score 13):

To `cd` to the previous directory, you can use one of the following commands in bash:

```
cd -
cd "$OLDPWD"
```

To `cd` to your home directory, use one of:

```
cd
cd ~
cd "$HOME"
```

If you want to undo multiple `cd`s, `cd` can't help you. You'll have to use the `pushd` and `popd` commands. Instead of `cd foo/bar`, do

```
pushd foo/bar
```

Then you can use the `popd` command to undo as many times as you have used `pushd`.

Example:

```
/tmp/lightdm-1.10.5 $ pushd ~
~ /tmp/lightdm-1.10.5
~ $ pushd devel
~/devel ~ /tmp/lightdm-1.10.5
~/devel $ popd
~ /tmp/lightdm-1.10.5
~ $ popd
/tmp/lightdm-1.10.5
/tmp/lightdm-1.10.5 $
```

Also see:

- [How do I use the pushd and popd commands?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/77077/70524)

Comment: Don't forget the obvious `cd /home/user`, too.  ☺

Answer (score 6):

`cd -` returns to the previous directory.

If you want to go to home dir specifically, use `cd`, `cd $HOME`, or `cd ~`.

Answer (score -1):

`cd ~` will work. `~` is basically a shortcut for `/home/user`. If `cd ~` takes you to the home folder, then use `cd ~/user` instead.

Comment: The answer may work for the particular case (if the current user is called `user` and if that’s indeed her home directory) but not for any other directory.