# What is linux command to navigate to the previous directory (or back)?

Tags: command-line, files, directory, cd

I think my observation linux to navigate to the previous directory (or back) command is `cd-` but it is not working code `cd-`

Comment: Do not add the dash. That is a completely invalid command, just by adding the dash makes the command invalid. To go back, simply type cd and press enter (again. no dash)

Comment: I don't really know if that was an accident or not when you put the dash, but it was done twice, so I can't tell.

Answer (score 8):

You need a space before the `-`, so that it is passed as an *argument* to the `cd` command:

From `man bash`:

> An argument of - is converted to $OLDPWD before the directory change is attempted.

This is different from `cd ..` which changes to the *parent* directory, rather than to `$OLDPWD`. You may of course define aliases for either or both if you wish, ex. `alias cd-='cd -'` and `alias cd..='cd ..'` but they are not defined as such by default.

See also:

- [How do I move back to original directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/703153/how-do-i-move-back-to-original-directory)

You might also want to take a look at the bash shell's `pushd` and `popd` commands, which allow more complete access to the directory stack.